# qiskit install error Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: python, installation, pip, qiskit

I was installing qiskit with python 3.10 using

```
pip install qiskit
```

I had this error message then retried to reinstall dependencies starting from scipy.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\V\Anaconda3\envs\quantum\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\V\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wzcm65xt\\numpy_c83cea5123ba4c3796a5f07a57f874a8\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\V\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wzcm65xt\\numpy_c83cea5123ba4c3796a5f07a57f874a8\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\V\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-5ph1znak\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\V\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cfe2bivd\overlay' --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\V\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-cfe2bivd\overlay\Include\numpy' Check the logs for full command output.
```

The only similar request was with out a solution.

Comment: Can you please link to the other question? Even if it wasn't answered, it may be a duplicate or there may be information that could help someone.

Comment: It was related to installation of psycopg2-binary to python 3.7
I didn't add a link because it had no actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work. Before typing in

```
pip install qiskit
```

I used

```
conda install scipy
```

Somehow it worked.

Comment: conda looks for and addresses conflicts in a way that pip doesn't, I believe.

Comment: May be it is an explanation. The trouble was that it tried install it multiple times. I found similar error and tried to do installation process with out automation to pin point an error source. It is usually related to some specific lib conflicts with known solution.